# How to get data from linked table?

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm new in VBA so i don't know how to get data from linked table in ms access, But i tried some code but it show this error

```
"Run time error '3219' 
Invalid Operation
```

I already search this error everywhere but not find right answer.

Code

```
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim db As DAO.Recordset
 Set db = CurrentDb

 Set rsHoliday = db.OpenRecordset("Holidays", dbOpenTable)
//Error Occur in this line
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a Table to a Recordset. Loose the dbOpenTable parameter from the code. It would compile just fine and do what you want. Unless you wish to open the table you need to use DoCmd.OpenTable

Comment: To add to this, `dbOpenDynaset` will allow for editable records and `dbOpenSnapshot` is a "read-only" snapshot of the data.